# How to configure the Browser View in Banshee?

Tags: 11.10, banshee

It appears that I am unable to  change the browser view in banshee via the GUI.

But surely it's possible to set the "artist list" column to something like "album-artist list" or "Year of publication list", isn't it?

Please tell me which file to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this. There is a coming feature in Banshee that will make it possible to use another view (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

I logged a bug relating to this.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662461

The banshee ppa now has a mostly working implementation of this - I've no idea if it will make its way into the main repo, but you can add the ppa if it is important enough for you and you don't mind the chance of some instability.
https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa